# Certificate Error with Rest API : PKIX path building failed

Tags: rest-api, webservices, ssl

I am getting this error

> "PKIX path building failed "

when i make Rest call to web-service. Earlier it was working fine, but recently some certificate expired from web-service side and this error started  coming.

When I contacted WS team , they said they install the certificate again and it should work fine.
though they installed the certificate , I am still getting the error.

One more thing, when I am making HTTP call instead of HTTPS , i don't get the error but response is also not coming. I am getting blank response.